# Mistake in resume sent; what to do?

Tags: application, cv, medicine

I am asking this question on behalf of my brother, in the U.S.

Yesterday, my brother submitted his application to a Physicians Assistant program, which has a very rigorous application process (not very different from medical school in terms of rigor). However, today he noticed that when he uploaded his resume, the formatting was slightly changed; a few words went from being in all caps to all lower case. Also, he noticed that he had made one small typo.

Would this look really bad and be percieved as carelesness? What should my brother do? As we see it, there are two options. Either do nothing, or send an email to the school explaining the situation (this seems like the best option to us). If the second is indeed best, how should he frame the email to minimize the damage?

Thanks.

Comment: We are not the Admissions Dept, so have no control over what they expect. However, multiple submissions will probably not help...

Comment: @SolarMike Could you please give a brief explanation of why  you think a second submission would be detrimental? Our logic was "It's probably better to warn them, rather than let them notice it on their own."

Comment: I wouldn’t worry too much if it’s just the fonts and one typo

Comment: @Spark Thanks for the response. Do you think it might be detrimental to send an email explaining it anyway?

Comment: I wouldn’t, it won’t help in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

You are risking drawing attention to a mistake that could otherwise go unnoticed.

Is resume the main part of the application? Or are there other parts, like an essay, recommendation letter, some all-important exam (like GRE for graduate study)?

Also, if there is time till deadline, consider waiting few days and then **updating** the resume with some new bit of information, like more detailed description of an experience that they might find relevant. An update to content is a lot more acceptable than fixing typos.

Comment: The application process has many other parts.

Comment: If there are many other parts THAT RECRUITERS WILL LIKELY READ instead of resume, then probably let resume stay as it is

Comment: Also really simple thing: if application is submitted on a website, then maybe that website will let you upload a new version of resume.